# Spring Hibernate configuration for maven multi module

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I have multi module project like below

- DbUtils

  - Doctor Module Project
  - Patient Module Project

I have configured hibernate in DbUtils project with configuration file as below

```
LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.test.dbutils.pojos" });
```

Now I want to use this session factory in both sub modules and I want to `setPackagesToScan` Project wise.
i.e for Doctor Module `com.test.doctor.pojos` and for Patient module `com.test.patient.pojos`

Q.1) How to achieve this?

Q.2) Is there any other better approach creating and using session factory in multi modules?

Comment: Suppose `@EntityScan` is an another approch. refer [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5401) example this may be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Hibernate4+ then you may want to go thru http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

Otherwise, to my knowledge, you have to let JVM know about set packagesToScan at compile time. If you are running Doctor and Patient as separate SpringBoot applications or so[but still leveraging upon common code in DBUtils] then you have option to pass the packages as String via some application.properties file and set the right POJO package in the child module.

If you have both Doctor and Patient running in the same application, you can atleast try to pass multiple packages `[sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.test.doctor.pojos", "com.test.patient.pojos" });]`